# How to compare column name of a List type object with a string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have List Type object in which I am passing data from the stored procedure. The result set has some columns which I need to compare with a string.
Ex. colName1 == "abc"

How to iterate through columns of the list and compare column names with a string? How to access text of the column?

```
modelSP.objAbsentDetail = dbOracle.STORED_PROC_DTL(ENGG, YY, MM, Location).ToList();

foreach(var item in model.objAbsentDetail)
        {
            //item.C1 (Column Name, not value) == "abc"
        }
```

Model Class:

```
public class abc
{
     public List<STORED_PROC_DTL_Result> objAbsentDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Using reflection?

Comment: But the column names won't change? If the SP returns a `C1` column, `STORED_PROC_DTL_Result.C1` will always contain that value. So... `if (nameof(item.C1) == "C1") {... }` will always yield true. This sounds like an XY problem. Instead properly explain your end goal and why you believe you need to know column names from property names for that, and perhaps something useful can be said.

Comment: No item.C1 will yield first-row value of C1 column, not the name 'C1'

Comment: It is `nameof(item.C1)`, which will return the name "C1".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use reflection for this you can have your properties be backed by a dictionary rather than a named variable :

```
private Dictionary<string, object> _values = new ...

public string C1{
  get{
    if(!_values.ContainsKey("C1"))
      return null;
    return (string)_values["C1"];
  }
  set{
    _values["C1"] = value;
  }
}
```

Then you can rummage in the _values.Keys for your column name